# Cookie error when using CGI::Session

Tags: perl, cgi, session-cookies

It's my first experiment with CGI::Sessions and I'm getting an error message in my logs that I don't know how to fix. It looks like the problem is on line 28 of my code, the $cookie variable in not imported:

> [Mon Aug 18 21:42:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Variable "$cookie" is not imported at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/login.pl line 28.
>   5028 [Mon Aug 18 21:42:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] \t(Did you mean &cookie instead?)
>   5029 [Mon Aug 18 21:42:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Variable "$cookie" is not imported at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/login.pl line 29.
>   5030 [Mon Aug 18 21:42:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] \t(Did you mean &cookie instead?)
>   5031 [Mon Aug 18 21:42:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Global symbol "$cookie" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/login.pl line 28.
>   5032 [Mon Aug 18 21:42:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Global symbol "$cookie" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/login.pl line 29.
>   5033 [Mon Aug 18 21:42:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Bareword "username" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/login.pl line 34.
>   5034 [Mon Aug 18 21:42:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Bareword "password" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/login.pl line 35.
>   5035 [Mon Aug 18 21:42:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Execution of /usr/lib/cgi-bin/login.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
>   5036 [Mon Aug 18 21:42:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: login.pl

Here's my code:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/perl -wT
  2 use strict;
  3 
  4 use CGI::Session;
  5 use CGI qw(:standard);
  6 
  7 my %names = map { $_ => 1 } param;
  8 my $open = "1234";
  9 
 10 sub windowLayout() {
 11           header,
 12           start_html("Input Form"),
 13           start_form,
 14           "Please enter your username:",
 15           textfield(-name=>'username',
 16                           -maxlength=>20),p,
 17           "Please enter your password:",
 18           password_field(-name=>'password',
 19                           -maxlength=>20),p,
 20           submit,hr
 21 }
 22 
 23 if ($names{username} and $names{password}) {
 24 
 25 my $cgi = new CGI;
 26 my $session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
 27 
 28 $cookie = $cgi->cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id);
 29 print $cgi->header(-cookie=>$cookie);
 30 
 31 my $username  = param("username");
 32 my $password  = param("password");
 33 
 34 $session->param(username, $username);
 35 $session->param(password, $password);
 36 
 37  if ($password ne $open) {
 38        print
 39         windowLayout(),
 40         end_form,
 41           p({-style=>'Color: red;'},
 42                  "Sorry wrong password!");
 43        print end_html;
 44   } else {
 45        print
 46           redirect("hello.pl");
 47   }
 48  }else {
 49     print
 50          windowLayout(),
 51          end_html;
 52  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using `strict` in your code (which is, of course, a great habit to get in to), you'll need to declare all of your variables with `my` (or something equivalent). You don't do that for `$cookie`.

So change:

```
$cookie = $cgi->cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id);
```

To:

```
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id);
```

For future reference, if you get a Perl error message that you don't understand, you can get more detail about the problem by adding `use diagnostics` to you code (but remember to remove it again once the problem is fixed).

You also have a couple of other errors. The strings 'username' and 'password' need to be quoted string on lines 34 and 35.